# My Android app doesn't receive FCM notification sent with a REST call

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm testing Firebase Cloud Messaging, I created an Android project thanks to this documentation :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Afterward I sent a notification thanks to the notification composer :

> https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/PROJECT-ID/notification

It works well, I received my notification in-app. So I conclude that my client is not the problem.

But it doesn't work with a REST call.

I did the following call :

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/messages:send
```

Header :

```
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN OAUTH2>
Content-Type: application/json
```

Body :

```
{
  "message":{
    "topic" : "mytopic",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

The response from googleapis was HTTP 200 with the body

```
{
    "name": "projects/<PROJECT-ID>/messages/<MESSAGE-ID>"
}
```

In my Android App I subscribed to the topic "mytopic" :

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("mytopic");
```

Comment: Are you able to send a message from the REST call directly to the device using the FCM Token of the device? That would be a good way to narrow down if the issue is with the topic.

Comment: Hi Jen, it's awkward but today it works well. yesterday I tried the legacy REST calls and I received the notification after more than 5mn or I had syn time out. Do you think it may be common (because FCM usage is free) ?